# how to convert non-F value into T

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame similar to this

```
name gender d1 d2  d3
dfd    M    F   F  F
adj    F    abc F  F
dfdf   F    F   df F
dfd    NA   F   F  dfd
daf    F    adf F  F
```

for column d1, d2, d3, I want to convert all non-F value (abc, df, adf, dfd, and many others) into T.

my current code is:

```
for item in d1, d2, d3:
    if item != F:
       return 'T'
```

This would work, but it runs really long. Is there a pandas command that does this directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```py
cols = ['d1', 'd2', 'd3']

df[cols] = df[cols].where(df[cols]=='F', 'T')
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
df[['d1','d2','d3']]=df[df[['d1','d2','d3']].isin(['F'])][['d1','d2','d3']].fillna('T')
```